# HA queue not transferring to other instances in JBoss

Tags: netty

While creating a HA queue in Jboss6.1.0.Final (using UDP_ASYNC as communication protocol and netty connector channel along with inifinispan cache config for replication), it seems that queue is not transferring to other nodes in cluster.

Can anybody please suggest any steps/solutions.